# VScode ,PHP starting server

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Hi I using the PHP Server plugin in VScode and there is [404] /welcome.php - No such file or directory show up but the server seen workng fine.I can interact with my page and the server will give respone

```
[Thu Mar 30 18:02:44 2023] PHP 8.2.4 Development Server (http://localhost:3000) started
[Thu Mar 30 18:02:44 2023] [::1]:52190 Accepted
[Thu Mar 30 10:02:44 2023] [404] /welcome.php - No such file or directory
[Thu Mar 30 18:02:44 2023] [::1]:52190 [200]: GET /welcome.php
[Thu Mar 30 18:02:44 2023] [::1]:52190 Closing
```

will this 404 error cause any problem? it there any way i can fix it?

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because it cannot find the "welcome.php" file. Can you go to the folder directory and check if the file exists? Additionally, I recommend the "Five Server" extension for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Sry can I ask where should I put my php file?

Comment: also you can see that in the line taht show 404 the time is different with others nto sure why this happen